# Finding the boundary points in a raster data file

Tags: r, raster, google-maps-static-api, ggmap

So, I have with me the center point and the zoom level.
I have to plot some points on the map.

The map is stored in a raster data file, and is displayed on the R's widget.

The issue is that when a point is received, I need to check whether it falls inside the data of this raster file or not.
If the point is in the raster file, then I can safely plot it.
If not, then I need to load another raster file which contains that point, and then plot the point.

The `raster` package of R has a function named `as.data.frame` which loads the raster data into the data frame.

Is it possible, then, to figure out which points (lats and lons) are at the four corners?
Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you not just limit the x and y axis of your plot to the extent of the ggnap?

Comment: @mnel Sorry, not well versed in R, so don't know how to do that.

Comment: It will depend on what you are using to create the plot. I will assume you are creating the plot using `ggmap()`, in which case the extent is set automatically to this. eg `hdf <- get_map(); .points <- data.frame(lon = 0, lat = 0);  ggmap(hdf, extent = 'device') + geom_point(data = .points,aes(x=lon,y=lat))` -- The point `0,0` is not within the extent of the raster, and is not plotted (as the warning tells you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is of RasterLayer class then `extent` will give you the extent of the raster
and `xmin`, '`min`, `ymax` and `xmax` to access the various slots.

eg

```
# create a dummy raster
r1 <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=0, xmx=10)
r1[] <-1

extent(r1)
## class       : Extent 
## xmin        : 0 
## xmax        : 10 
## ymin        : -90 
## ymax        : 90
```

You can access the various slots using

```
xmin(r1)
## [1] 0
xmax(r1)
##[1] 10
ymin(r1)
## [1] -90
ymax(r1)
## [1] 90
```

If your data is a `SpatialGridDataFrame` then `bbox` will return the bounding box

```
.grid <- as(r1,'SpatialGridDataFrame')

bbox(.grid)
##    min max
## s1   0  10
##  2 -90  90
```

### Does my xy coordinate lie within the raster boundary

you can use `cellFromXY` to find the cell `id`, and it will return `NA` if it is outside the extext

eg

```
 # some data
 .points <- rbind(c(1,1),c(-4,1))
 # the first point lies within the raster, the second not

 # cell from XY will tell you this.
 cellFromXY(r1,.points)
 ## [1] 1116   NA
```

### EDIT for ggmap

if you have a map acquired by `get_map`, it is a `ggmap` object, and will not work  with the package `raster` *without some help from you* .

you can obtain the bounding box as the `bb` attribute.

```
  hdf <- get_map()
  attr(hdf,'bb')
##    ll.lat    ll.lon   ur.lat    ur.lon
## 1 29.38048 -95.80204 30.14344 -94.92313
```

A helper function that will create a RasterStack from a ggmap object

```
ggmap_rasterlayer <- function(map){
  map_bbox <- attr(map, 'bb') 
  .extent <- extent(as.numeric(map_bbox[c(2,4,1,3)]))
  my_map <- raster(.extent, nrow= nrow(map), ncol = ncol(map))
  rgb_cols <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(col2rgb(map))), c('red','green','blue'))
  red <- my_map
  values(red) <- rgb_cols[['red']]
  green <- my_map
  values(green) <- rgb_cols[['green']]
  blue <- my_map
  values(blue) <- rgb_cols[['blue']]
  stack(red,green,blue)

}

my_map <- ggmap_rasterlayer(hdf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using `ggmap` to download the static maps of google and then saving the result in a file with extension `.rda`. I'll need the `gdal` package to make this work.

Comment: If you are using `ggmap` you should say so! The package `raster` creates `RasterLayers` and won't work natively. I'm editing the response

Comment: sorry, indeed I should have mentioned.

Comment: I have shown how to convert a `ggmap` object to a `RasterStack` which will let you use `cellFromXY`

Comment: All thanks for your help. I'll get back if I face any further problems.